# R How to convert decimal numeric(year.month) to date format

Tags: r, date, decimal

My data has date info with numeric format of decimal, and which makes October subset as Jan.(010=>1)
Because of this, as.POSIXct and as.Date are not applicable.
When using substring(or substr) to take last two digit, it automatically converted  to character, then 010 becomes 1.

```
num<-c(2019.009, 2019.010,2019.011)

Y<-as.numeric(substring(num,1,4))
M<-as.numeric(substr(num, 7,8))
as.yearmon(paste(Y,M),"%Y %m")
  [1] "Sep 2019" "Jan 2019" "Nov 2019"

as.POSIXct(num, tx="GMT","%Y %m")
  Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(num, tx = "GMT", "%Y %m") : 
  'origin' must be supplied
as.Date(num, "%Y %m")
  Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: Why aren’t you reading the error message?  The yearmon construction is numeric so you need an origin.

Comment: The purported duiplicate is for character input but this one is for numeric input.

Answer (score 4):

in base R you could use functions like `strptime/as.Date` +`strftime/format`  etc etc.

method 1:

```
strftime(strptime(sprintf("%.3f01",num),"%Y.0%m%d"),"%b %Y")

[1] "Sep 2019" "Oct 2019" "Nov 2019"
```

method 2:

```
format(as.Date(sprintf("%.3f01",num),"%Y.0%m%d"),"%b %Y")

[1] "Sep 2019" "Oct 2019" "Nov 2019"
```

Of course you could mix the functions up, eg `strptime` + `format` etc

if you are using the `zoo` library, you could do:

```
zoo::as.yearmon(sprintf("%.3f", num), "%Y.0%m")

[1] "Sep 2019" "Oct 2019" "Nov 2019"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprintf` to have fixed number of decimal places and use `sub` to extract first 4 digits and last 2 digits in the data and convert to year month class.

```
num<-c(2019.009, 2019.010,2019.011)
zoo::as.yearmon(sub('(\\d{4})\\..(\\d{2})$', '\\1-\\2', sprintf('%0.3f', num)))
#[1] "Sep 2019" "Oct 2019" "Nov 2019"
```

---

Your original code will also work after using `sprintf` :

```
num <- sprintf('%0.3f', num)
Y<-as.numeric(substring(num,1,4))
M<-as.numeric(substr(num, 7,8))
zoo::as.yearmon(paste(Y,M),"%Y %m")
#[1] "Sep 2019" "Oct 2019" "Nov 2019"
```

Comment: what does '%0.3f mean?

Comment: It keeps 3 decimal places in `num` so the last 0 is not dropped in `2019.010`.